# Where is the current version of CiviCRM stored for D8/D9 instances?

Tags: version

An upgrade of CiviCRM (D9) has resulted in this error/warning

"Your database is marked with an unexpected version number: 5.45.4. The v5.45.3 codebase may not be compatible with your database state. You will need to determine the correct version corresponding to your current database state. You may want to revert to the codebase you were using until you resolve this problem.
OR if this is a manual install from git, you might want to fix civicrm-version.php file."

The civicrm-version.php file does not show current or any specific version. Has this location been deprecated for D9?   Is there another location that should be reviewed?

This issue (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/10) suggests that the civicrm-version.php file should include:

[image]

Is that still accurate or is there another location?

Answer (score 1):

xml/version.xml

In the database it's in civicrm_domain.

It isn't cms-specific.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that civicrm-version.php is no longer relevant?

Comment: It's relevant in that you shouldn't delete civicrm-version.php, but the version itself isn't stored in that file.